# Access SQL: Self join without cross duplicates

Tags: sql, ms-access, duplicates, self-join

Table:

```
  Bag | Weight
------------
  A   | 2
  B   | 2
  C   | 3
```

I want to know which bags have similar weights; normally I would self-join on the *Weight* column; but I don't want cross duplications; that is if I have A-B, I don't want B-A.

Query:

```
SELECT lhs.bag, rhs.bag
FROM myTable AS lhs INNER JOIN myTable AS rhs ON lhs.weight = rhs.weight;
```

Result:

```
lhs.bag | rhs.bag
-----------------
    A   |   A
    A   |   B
    B   |   B
    B   |   A
    C   |   C
```

I don't want the row B|A in the results, because similarly it has been in A|B.

Expected Table:

```
 lhs.bag | rhs.bag
-----------------
    A   |   A
    A   |   B
    B   |   B
    C   |   C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend the join condition

```
SELECT lhs.bag, rhs.bag
FROM myTable AS lhs 
INNER JOIN myTable AS rhs ON lhs.weight = rhs.weight AND
                             lhs.bag <= rhs.bag;
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know, it was this easy.